# wp enqueue style not working on child theme wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

i just got into a job and i am recieving training for wordpress. i tried making a a child theme and enqueue style in functions.php .  i have no idea what i am doing wrong. pls help as the style.css is not loading what so ever. i tried the import way, still its not working.

Thanx in adv

**code for functions.php**

```
   <?php
    function avudo_add_styles(){
        wp_enqueue_style ('main_css', get_stylesheet_uri());
    }
    add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','avudo_add_styles');
    ?>
```

style.css

```
/*
 Theme Name:   Twenty fourteen Child
 Theme URI:    http://example.com/twenty-fifteen-child/
 Description:  Twenty Fifteen Child Theme
 Author:       John Doe
 Author URI:   http://example.com
 Template:     twentyfourteen
 Version:      1.0.0
 License:      GNU General Public License v2 or later
 License URI:  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
 Tags:         light, dark, two-columns, right-sidebar, responsive-layout, accessibility-ready
 Text Domain:  twenty-fourteen-child
*/

/*testing*/
body{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: this page explains it: https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Comment: i am referring that only but the style is not loading. if it is working the background should turn blue but it isnt

Comment: yaaa the child theme is activated, and i am sure about it bcoz i cant see any style of the parent theme

Comment: have you tried to write the code as they explain in the link in my first comment, its different than yours

Comment: tried it as mentioned. not working. i am only getting the content not the styling.

Comment: finally!!! got it right. all i did wrong was i had created the index.php file . i deleted that from the child directory and it worked.. thanks to all who responded. appreciate it!!